# How should i Implement LeaveHistory in Employee Maintenance System

Tags: java

I am developing a basic Employee Maintenance System in Java. I need to add a functionality for an Employee to Request for Leave? I am confused which would be a better way to Implement that 
1. Create a separate Common List for all employees 
2. Create a List inside my Employee Entity, so single list will be associated with a single employee
3. Any other opinion?

Comment: For leave request table, have an employee ID as foreign key..

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the second option and create a `List<Request>` inside your `Employee` entity, as I don't think a `Request` may exist without an `Employee` who requested it.

Also, I would go with a `Request` field and not a `RequestLeave` as this may be too specific and you would want to be able to set other types of `Request` as `DISEASE` or `MOTHERHOOD` for example.

Following this, you would have your `Employee` entity

```
public class Employee {

    // all fields for Employee

    final List<Request> requests;

}
```

A `Request` entity

```
public class Request {

    private Long id;
    private DateTime timestamp;
    private Reason reason;

}
```

And a list of reasons for this `Request`

```
public Enum Reason {

    LEAVE,
    SICKNESS,
    MOTHERHOOD;

}
```

An advantage of this above the first option is, if you want to persist your data into a database, you would be able to set a relation between `Employee` and `Request` in an easy way.